# how to handle adding duplicate item in react

Tags: reactjs

I have to raise an alert message if a user tried to add a item twice into cart.(in my project country). but I failed. here is my live webpage link:

https://ultra-nation99.netlify.app/

if you press a button multiple time you will understand what's wrong with my code. here is my parent App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Country from "./Components/Country/Country";
import Cart from "./Components/Cart/Cart";

function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setCountries(data));
  }, []);

  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  // Adding Item and handling duplicacy
  const handleAddCountry = (country) => {
    const newCountry = [...cart, country];
    setCart(newCountry);
    cart.find((item) =>
      item.numericCode === country.numericCode
        ? window.alert("You have already added this country")
        : setCart(newCountry)
    );
  };

  // // Stop Adding Duplicate Item
  // const handleDuplicateCountry = (country) => {
  //   const newCountry = cart.filter((item) =>
  //     item.numericCode === country.numericCode
  //       ? window.alert("You have already added this country")
  //       : setCart(newCountry)
  //   );
  // };

  // Removing Item
  const handleDeleteCountry = (country) => {
    const newCountry = cart.filter((item) => {
      return item.numericCode !== country.numericCode;
    });
    setCart(newCountry);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header d-flex">
        <div className="countries">
          <h1>Countries Info</h1>

          {countries.map((country) => (
            <Country
              country={country}
              key={country.numericCode}
              handleAddCountry={handleAddCountry}
              handleDeleteCountry={handleDeleteCountry}
            ></Country>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="cart">
          <h1>Population</h1>
          <Cart cart={cart}></Cart>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is Country.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Country.css";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

const Country = (props) => {
  // console.log(props);
  const {
    name,
    capital,
    population,
    region,
    currencies,
    flag,
    languages,
  } = props.country;

  return (
    <div className="country-info mb-5">
      <img src={flag} alt="" />
      <h3>Country Name: {name}</h3>
      <h3>Capital Name: {capital}</h3>
      <h3>Population: {population}</h3>
      <h3>Region: {region}</h3>
      {currencies.map((currency, idx) => (
        <h3 key={idx}>Currency: {currency.name}</h3>
      ))}
      {languages.map((language) => (
        <h3>language: {language.name}</h3>
      ))}
      <Button
        vaiant="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          props.handleAddCountry(props.country);
        }}
      >
        Add Country
      </Button>
      <Button
        vairant="primary"
        onClick={() => props.handleDeleteCountry(props.country)}
      >
        Remove Country
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Country;
```

here is Cart.js:

```
import React from "react";

const Cart = (props) => {
  // console.log(props.cart);
  const GrossPopulation = props.cart;
  let totalPopulation = 0;
  totalPopulation = GrossPopulation.reduce(
    (acc, current) => acc + current.population,
    0
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Country Added: {GrossPopulation.length}</h3>
      <h3>Total Population: {totalPopulation}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Please anybody explain what's the mistake I have made in //Adding item and Handling duplicate add part in my App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only call `setCart` with the new country added to the end of the array if that country doesn't already exist in the array:

```
const handleAddCountry = (country) => {
  if (cart.some(item => item.numericCode === country.numericCode)) {
    window.alert("You have already added this country");
    return;
  }
  setCart([...cart, country]);
};
```